# How can I rotate my material in shader graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

My project that was from tutorial made by Sebastian Lague about procedural generation and I upgraded it to URP
**Before upgrade it looked like this:**

[image]

I needed to recreate the material from scratch using the Unity shader graph following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJSxqr3a0cA but I changed the textures to colors and its looking like this[image]

Here is how the material graph is looking like:[image]
I don't know why its on the wrong axis

Comment: did you download his project and look at his stuff and play spot the difference?

Comment: wheres your position node?

Comment: Yes I downloaded his project and tried to find diffrences but only one is hi is using textures not a colors. There is no position node

Comment: where are you expecting to get the height of the terrain from then?

Comment: There are nodes that defines the height for the layers

Comment: yess but the thats like saying someone is talk when they reach this mark.. you have to measure them to find out where they are........ i just made a gradiated plane for my 2d game using his thing.. spot on..

Comment: I have two nodes that defines the height (like water height starts at 0 and sand height starts at 0.3) then Im using the Inverse Lerp where A is water height, B is sand height and T is from split G like in the tutorial

Comment: right and what height are you comparing that too? you dont seem to have a position to compare it

Comment: And if you look at the third screen where this graph is shown, you'll see that everything looks as it should. The problem only occurs when I'm already applying it to an object

Comment: Im comparing the height to Split G as a parametr A and first layer height as a parametr B

Comment: I dont see how without position you arent getting the height  - and i cant see a position node in your graph, you said you followed the totiral and i get you and I both used colours not textures, but you changed other things so, Id say, go back and stick with the colours but do his graph not your.s.. as his seems to work

Comment: If you need here is the shader: [link](https://github.com/Drunkiel/Crystalside/tree/main/Assets/Graphics/Materials/Shaders)